# How to make a flexbox item in the corner and responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to css and I want to let five boxes lined up horizontally in the top left corner and the last one stay in the bottom right corner even if you resize the browser.I try to use flex to do this but failed to make the F element in the right corner.Can you tell me how to do this?

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#A, #B, #C, #D, #E, #F {
    background: #eeeff2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    border-left: 10px dotted #D0D0FF;
    margin-right:10px;
}

p {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#A:hover, #B:hover, #C:hover, #D:hover, #E:hover, #F:hover {
    background: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="styleB.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="A">
                <p>A</p>
            </div>
            <div id="B">
                <p>B</p>
            </div>
            <div id="C">
                <p>C</p>
            </div>
            <div id="D">
                <p>D</p>
            </div>
            <div id="E">
                <p>E</p>
            </div>
            <div id="F">
                <p>F</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried absolutely positioning the F element in the right corner?

Comment: `#F { margin-left: auto; }`

Comment: I use the absolutely positioning the F element and it works.Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to need set margin for last-child `#F{ margin-left:auto; }`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#A,
#B,
#C,
#D,
#E,
#F {
  background: #eeeff2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border-left: 10px dotted #D0D0FF;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#F {
  margin-left: auto;
}

p {
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#A:hover,
#B:hover,
#C:hover,
#D:hover,
#E:hover,
#F:hover {
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="A">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div id="B">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div id="C">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div id="D">
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div id="E">
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
  <div id="F">
    <p>F</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This [Scrimba](https://scrimba.com/course/gflexbox/enrolled) tutorial will help you to know details about CSS flexbox.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have read the tutorial but what if I want to place the F element in the bottom right corner?

Comment: I use the `position: absolute;` and it works fine.Out of curiosity, can flex-box place the F element in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Yes ! `align-items` , `align-self` property and flex-direction will help you to position individual item